# MySQL - No lock while selecting rows in table

Tags: mysql, locking

I'm starting to study MySQL syntax and now I'm asking how to lock / unlock tables.

After a bit of research, it seems that mysql does not provide a single "nolock" key word.

But if I try to execute the following query:

```
select *from logs NOLOCK order by timestamp desc;
```

no errors occur. So, is there a standard way in order to achieve this?

Comment: PL/SQL isn't MySQL... `select * from logs NOLOCK` is valid MySQL only because you aliased table logs with the alias NOLOCK

Comment: Pardon @RaymondNijland, why do you say it is an alias? shouldn't it be "from logs AS NOLOCK" in order to be what you said?
Thanks for the answer

Comment: Pardon again, i read that table aliases can be used without "as" key word too. So the problem doesn't exist.

Comment: PL/SQL is the in-database programming language provided as part of Oracle database. It is entirely unrelated to MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

`NOLOCK` is not an option supported by MySQL.

It's a feature specific to Microsoft SQL Server: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/hints-transact-sql-table

You must understand that even though SQL is a common standard, each company who offers a SQL-compliant database product has implemented their own extensions to standard SQL. Therefore a product like Microsoft SQL Server has some syntax features that are not supported — and not needed — by other RDBMS products.

MySQL is not Microsoft SQL Server. They are two different implementations of RDBMS.

As Raymond commented above, you unintentionally used `NOLOCK` in a place where it would be interpreted by MySQL as a table alias.

```
... FROM logs [AS] NOLOCK ...
```

The SQL standard supports making the `AS` keyword optional when definining table aliases and column aliases. This can cause some weird surprises, even though it's technically legal syntax to omit the `AS` keyword.